# Tagging Aliases

Tags: mysql, sql

Lets say that i have a tagging system, which stores the tags for every article as a list of Integers. Anyone can post an Article, which results in the tags becoming incredibly cluttered, for example the tags could be x and y, but both mean x.

What i want to be able to do is create two tables, one with an ID and Tag columns (Tags), and the other with Alias and Tag_ID columns (Aliases), what type of SQL Query would work the most efficiently to get the Tag that could be referenced as an alias, when searching through articles.

The best i can come up with is two queries, the first to get any aliases (then using code to check if count == 1), then grabbing the final tag from the Tags Table. Which is...

```
SELECT Tag_ID FROM Aliases WHERE Alias='UserInput';
#Perform check to see if there are 0 results
Select ID FROM Tags WHERE Tag='UserInput';
```

Is there a way to do this like

```
SELECT Tags.Tag FROM Tags
INNER JOIN Aliases
ON Aliases.Tag_ID=Tags.ID
WHERE ...?
```

I cannot figure out how to do the WHERE clause of the SQL Statement, if it would even work the way i want...The best i can think of is to use an OR clause and check Aliases.Alias and Tags.Tag separately...

Sorry if this doesn't make sense, it's all concept information, that i want to get correct on the SQL side to make sure that it won't be a roadblock in the development once i start...

**Edit:**
As Clarification, I'm attempting to resolve "y" to "x". So if in the `Aliases` table, there is an `alias` of *CSharp* with the `tag_id` of *1*, and in the `Tags` table, there is a `tag` of *C#* with the `id` of *1*, the SQL statement should retrieve *C#*, irrelevant of if there is or isn't an Alias and irrelevant of which was used to search.

I want to be able to do that in a Single Efficient SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want

```
select a.tag_id, Tags.tag 
from tags
join aliases a on a.tag_id = tags.id
where tags.tag = a.alias
```

If you want to search for alias containing the tag then you can use the `like` keyword :

```
select a.tag_id, Tags.tag
from tags
join aliases a on a.tag_id = tags.id
where tags.tag like '%' a.alias '%'
```

Conclusion : it is not possible to do what you want, as you can't guess what is the link between a tag and a word. However, the `like` solution is probably the closest solution you can have.

Comment: That does seem to be it, i'll set up a test database to try it out, to see if it does as expected.

Comment: Sadly it didn't work, and when testing it, changing the select to a.* and Tags.*, and removing the where returned when searching for the alias, but not the actual tag.

Comment: The new SQL Doesn't return any results, i also edited the question to add some more clarification as to what i want to do and the results i am expecting.

Comment: It appears you have miss understood my intentions, the purpose of the Alias table is to redirect to the real tag. Say someone is searching for an article about C#, but they use CSharp, i want to find articles with the Tag C#, rather then returning 0 results. The first Query that you gave got correct Tag if an Alias was used, but if the real tag was used, then it would return nothing, because the search query will never be both "C#" and "CSharp"

Comment: Ahh, as i initially thought, it would seem that what i want to do would require at minimum two queries to be executed if no alias was used. Luckily that'll only have to be done when searching. Thank you for your help.